# jqGrid: How can I change the width of the jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I would like to change the width of a jqGrid. I tried to set the width in my griddefinition:

```
   width: '800px'
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use the `setGridWidth` property

```
 $('#gridId').jqGrid('setGridWidth', '800');
```

If you want the grid to re-size dynamically, hook into the window re-size function, but remember to set the initial width

```
 var DataGrid = $('#gridId');

 //sets the grid size initially
 DataGrid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', parseInt($(window).width()) - 20);    

 //handles the grid resize on window resize
 $(window).resize(function () { 
       DataGrid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', parseInt($(window).width()) - 20); 
 });
```